# Django ContentTypes versus OneToOneField versus Multi-Table structure

Tags: mysql, django, schema

I'm thinking over the schema design of my app and I'm not sure that I'm approaching it correctly.

I have a model called Activity, which stores general data about an activity (start/end dates, tags, title, associated url, images, etc).

There are several categories of Activities, each of which requires different columns.  If I were to build this app in Mongo, that would be easy, I would just created a nested structure for the particular Activity with all of its unique attributes.  In MySQL, it's a bit more challenging (for me anyway).

So far, I've decided to go with the contenttypes framework.

```
    class Activity(models.Model):
        data_source = models.ForeignKey('source.Source')
        venues = models.ManyToManyField('venue.Venue', blank=True, null=True)
        tags = models.ManyToManyField('tag.Tag', blank=True, null=True)
        checkout_url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
        date_available = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
        date_expires = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
        small_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=settings.ACTIVITY_IMAGE_DIRECTORY, blank=True, null=True)
        big_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=settings.ACTIVITY_IMAGE_DIRECTORY, blank=True, null=True)
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        full_title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        short_title = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True, null=True)
        slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
      # Handle Generic Relations
        content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
        details_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
        details = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'details_object_id')
```

My concern is that I've heard mixed reviews about Generic Relations (colleagues have complained that queries are slow and unwieldy at times).

Instead, I suppose that I could create separate Details models to represent the unique details of the Activity and then link back to the Activity via OneToOneFields. I worry, though, that multiple model types would introduce issues around attribute lookups.  If I had two models like this:

```
  class DetailsA(models.Model):
      activity = models.OneToOneField(Activity)
      ....

  class DetailsB(models.Model):
      activity = models.OneToOneField(Activity)
      ...
```

calling activity_instance.detailsB would raise an AttributeError in the event that this activity contains a DetailsA relationship, right?  I could handle this by defining a model property, but it would seem less than ideal.

I could also make Activity an abstract class and inherit from it, but that would require extra ORM work when looking up Activities across multiple categories.

My instinct is to go with Generic Relationships and denormalize some of the data (i.e. through a details_name column).  Over time, I'd probably just move a lot of this data toward denormalized NoSQL storage anyway.

Does this seem like a good choice?